# Quelle est la différence entre « s'apercevoir » et « comprendre » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Y a-t-il une différence entre *s'apercevoir* et *comprendre* ? Si oui, laquelle ?

Par exemple, y a-t-il une différence entre

> À ce cours on s'est aperçu que …

et

> À ce cours on a compris que …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*S'apercevoir* de quelque chose n'a pas le même sens que de le *comprendre*.

*Comprendre* signifie bien qu'on maîtrise maintenant quelque chose qu'on ne maîtrisait pas avant ou qu'on en a saisit l'importance.

**Exemple :** *J'ai compris comment fonctionne cette machine.* ou *Nous avons compris pourquoi il était important de regarder à gauche et à droite avant de traverser la route.*

Tandis que *s'apercevoir* est souvent lié à la vision (d'ailleurs il y a *voir* dedans) même si l'expression a quelque peu évolué. On peut aussi dire *se rendre compte que*.

On peut par exemple s'apercevoir que quelqu'un n'est plus là ou qu'un objet a changé de couleur. S'apercevoir de quelque chose est généralement accompagné d'un étonnement, la chose dont on s'est aperçue étant souvent inattendue.

Comment: +1 pour votre révélation de l'intuition : « ... s'apercevoir est souvent lié à la vision **(d'ailleurs il y a voir dedans)** ... ».

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit Et il y a *voir* également dans *ivoire* et *abreuvoir*, mais ça ne prouve rien. S'apercevoir n'a aucun lien avec la vision en particulier, pas plus qu'avec les autres sens.

Answer (score 1):

L'idée de *compréhension* est déjà clairement établie dans la réponse de JéromeJ, je ne la reprends pas.

En revanche, il me semble que ce n'est pas tout-à-fait ça pour *s'apercevoir*.

- **Percevoir** quelque chose, c'est l'avoir dans son champ de perception, cette grande quantité de bruits, d'images, d'odeurs, etc. que notre cerveau reçoit à chaque instant.
- **Apercevoir**, c'est porter son attention sur l'une de ces perceptions, la sortir du flot des perceptions inconscientes, que ce soit simplement pour la considérer, pour la contempler, ou pour y réfléchir.

**En résumé : S'apercevoir** (de quelque chose), **c'est prendre conscience** (d'une perception ou) **d'une idée que l'on avait déjà.**

On utilise souvent dans le même sens le verbe *réaliser*.

Pour approfondir la question de la distinction entre *perception* et *aperception*, voir notamment Leibniz, *"La théorie des petites perceptions"*.

Answer (score 0):

S'apercevoir est une expression, c'est une image passée dans la langage commun. Le terme exacte est bien "comprendre".